# Error: Not Found at Gaxios.<anonymous> when trying to get history list from Gmail

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I'm trying to process a push notification from Gmail by follow the instruction from [this link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html#0). I modified some code to read from historyId instead of most recent message like recommended in the guide.

It's normally work find but sometime the problem occurred after received a push notification. The script failed to call Gmail API:

```
gmail-watch-fs yv1ke4cc0tk8 Error: Not Found
at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:73:27)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

Here is the line that cause error:

```
const historyRes = await gmail.users.history.list({
  userId: "me",
  startHistoryId: historyId,
  historyTypes: ["messageAdded"],
})
```

I found a Japanese site suggest to enable IAM API but it's already enabled in my case. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because I try to listen to many subscribed email address by only one Cloud Function instance. It is solved by generate more Cloud Function (one per each subscribed email).